# Calling a class from a class with parameters (Cannot resolve symbol)

Tags: java, android, class

I'm pretty new to programming so it might be that I've gotten the whole idea wrong here but..

I have two classes, other is the main class (Main) and the second (DrawingLines) is just plain one. I'm trying to call an onDraw method from the DrawingLines in my main class.

I did a bit of research but all i found was to use

```
DrawingLines draw = new DrawingLines ();
draw.onDraw
```

And I think this is how it's supposed to be but I just cant figure out what parametres I should use. You can see the parametres I've been trying to use in the example below, but AndroidStudio just gives "Cannot resolve symbol".

Main class:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    parent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
            text.setText("Touch at " + (int)ev.getX() + ", " + (int)ev.getY());
            return true;
        }
    });

}

DrawingLines draw = new DrawingLines(Context context);
draw.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

DrawingLines class:

```
class DrawingLines extends View {

public DrawingLines(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect pallo = new Rect();
    pallo.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() / 2);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(pallo, blue);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You're passing `Context context` as a parameter, don't you have to pass `this.getApplicationContext()` instead ?

Comment: Thanks @Asew that helped me out a bit. This is just a test, but i wanted my drawing method to be in a separate class so my main would stay clean and easy to follow. When i get this work I'm going to make it so that it will draw a line from where you press on the screen to the closest point marked on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, if you want to draw something you don't have to force it programmatically. `DrawingLines draw = new DrawingLines(Context context);
   draw.onDraw(canvas)`
2. Put your view `DrawingLines` inside layout `R.layout.activity_main` and create variable use `findViewById`.
3. Then you can perform `drawingLines.invalidate()` on that view, so the View will be redrawn (method `void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` will be called).

Comment: Not sure if I got your point correct but heres what I added to the xml 

`<view
    android:id="@+id/DrawingLines"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />`
 And then I added this to the main: 
`View draw = (View) findViewById(R.id.DrawingLines);
        draw.invalidate(); `

If i used `DrawingLines.invalidate();` it gave me an error that invalidate is non-static..

This is how I got it error free, but it still crashes on emulator. Any tips or advices?

Comment: Oh yeah and I changed the id to draw and fixed main to `View draw = (View) findViewById(R.id.draw);`

Comment: yes, you should do  `DrawingLines view = (DrawingLines) findViewById(R.id.draw)`, and then when you want force redrawn use `view.invalidate()`. When your view becomes visible `onDraw` is called automatically you should only use `view.invalidate()` for example if you change something inside DrawingLines and wants to redraw it.

Comment: Hmm.. It still keeps on crashing. Reading the errors from Android monitor it says: "Binary XML file line #10: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

Line 10 on xml is "<view".

Comment: Did you add view to XML with hole path e.g. <com.blablabla.DrawingLines...?

Comment: Yeah now its right I got that wrong and I had also accidentally deleted one of my textviews. It's now saying that because custom View is not using 2- or 3- argumen View constructors; XML attributes will not work.. Any help on this? Really big thank you for helping me out so much, I should definetly go to library and read a book about using XML with java. EDIT: It already looks like it should in Preview so this is not far away.

Comment: Woohoo I got the last problem! I had to add parametre `AttributeSet attributeSet` to my DrawingLines custom View class to make it work. Again, thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not in a method:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        parent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
                text.setText("Touch at " + (int)ev.getX() + ", " + (int)ev.getY());
                return true;
            }
        });

    DrawingLines draw = new DrawingLines(this.getApplicationContext());
    draw.onDraw(canvas);

    }//onCreate

}//class main
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, just plain mistake but it didn't help with getting the parameter work. Asews comment that said I should use `this.getApplicationContext()` fixed the problem with the DrawingLines parameter. Still have to figure out how to get it to run onDraw

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple project that can draw by finger (I put all staff that performs draw in custom view)

DrawView:

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    private final static String LOG = "CUSTOM_LOG";

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path = new Path();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d(LOG, "init");
        setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d(LOG, "onDraw");
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            float x = motionEvent.getX();
            float y = motionEvent.getY();
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(LOG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                    path.moveTo(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d(LOG, "ACTION_MOVE");
                    path.lineTo(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(LOG, "ACTION_UP");
                    path.reset();
                    break;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.gitlab.onreg01.simpledrawexample.DrawView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[project repository](https://gitlab.com/onreg01/SimpleDrawExample)